# Define a preprocessor macro value from a shell script in iOS

Tags: ios, shell, jenkins, macros, preprocessor

We have an app that we want uploaded to a site with a different app id based on the the environment it's being built in. In the project we have a Release preprocessor macro set to MY_CONFIGURATION=$(MY_CONFIGURATION) and we set a default value to 3 in the user-defined settings. In our define where we assign the app id string value based off the macro define, we also have the fallback that if the value is not defined, use the value 1. The problem is when we build off Jenkins, the script assigned value (2) is overwritten by the default value from the user-defined settings (3).

Here's the line we are using in the build.sh file

```
xcodebuild -scheme ${SCHEME} -sdk ${SDK} -destination generic/platform=iOS CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${PROFILE}" MY_CONFIGURATION="${BUILD_ENV}" build
```

I know the correct value is being placed, as the console output from Jenkins shows the following

```
10:58:46 + xcodebuild -scheme MGO -sdk iphoneos9.0 -destination generic/platform=iOS 'CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=X' MY_CONFIGURATION=2 build
10:58:47 Build settings from command line:
10:58:47 CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = X
10:58:47 MY_CONFIGURATION = 2
10:58:47 SDKROOT = iphoneos9.0
```

The build uploads to the correct environment, build the #define within the code that sets the app id based on the value set displays the default value set (3) instead of the script value set (2). Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Note: I've also tried

```
xcodebuild -scheme ${SCHEME} -sdk ${SDK} -destination generic/platform=iOS CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${PROFILE}" OTHER_CFLAGS="-DMY_CONFIGURATION="${BUILD_ENV}"" build
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) to build and it works perfect. 
I think it works the same way in your situation and you can give it a try. Here's what I do.

`xctool -workspace productname.xcworkspace -scheme "$scheme" archive -archivePath $archivePath GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS="MY_CONFIGURATION=2 MY_ANOTHER_CONFIGURATION=1"`

What makes it work is [GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW14).

`GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS_NOT_USED_IN_PRECOMPS="MY_CONFIGURATION=2 MY_ANOTHER_CONFIGURATION=1"`

You can try to append this line above to your command. Make sure the value is a number. I failed when tried to use a string value. And there's another related keyword [GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW13) in the doc.